# Nested condition resulting empty page in smarty

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I am trying to filter out the prices with a nested `foreach` and if statement in smarty, but whenever i use if statement inside `foreach` loop it results in blank page.

Here is code causing issue

```
 {foreach $value.Regstration as $price}
    {if($price.price gt 0)}
        <br>{var_dump($price.price)} <br>
    {/if}
 {/foreach}
```

Even i tried with this

```
  {foreach $value.Regstration as $price}
    {if(1==1)}
        <br>{var_dump($price.price)} <br>
    {/if}
 {/foreach}
```

This is also returning blank page

But without if statement i am getting result like this

```
     float(14.95)

     float(-1)

    float(-1)

    float(-1)
```

So can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong or if not can anyone tell me how can i filter the prices equal to or lower then zero.

Comment: A tip: when working with `var_dump` and a framework, use `die()` or `exit` afterwards. Usually a framework will process output from elsewhere and you will not see the `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{foreach $value.Regstration as $price}
    {if 1 == 1}

        <!--
            For debug:

            {$price|var_dump}
        -->

        <br>{$price.price|var_dump}<br>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```